# Should I add "ALL" value in a table to retrieve all its values?

Tags: database

I have a `region` table in which I store master region data like Europe, America. etc. Now,  in the region drop down in the UI I want to add an option to select all regions. Should i add a new record "ALL" in the `region` table or should I add the "ALL" option only in the UI?  Also in the JSP (UI) i retrieve the region from DB (EJB) and show the list in the JSP page.

Answer (score 6):

Add it in the UI, otherwise you're breaking your data model.